# activate button after setTimeout ()

Tags: angular

I started to discover the environment of angular I have to install the environment as the video tells me. And I added a first component and the second component.And i added the button **save** and in component I add this code which already contains a deactivated button and after 4 seconds and then it will be active

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h2>Mes materiels</h2>
     <ul class="list-group">
       <app-materiel></app-materiel>
       <app-materiel></app-materiel>
       <app-materiel></app-materiel>
     </ul>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!isAuth" >Test Btn</button>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then in **app.component.ts** file and I added this code in which I define the function of the button to activate after 4 seconds

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
}) 
export class AppComponent {
isAuth=false;
constructor(){
  setTimeout(
    ()=>{
     this.isAuth=true;
   }, 4000
 );
 }
}
```

I do not know why the button does not activate after 4 seconds? and how can I find fault with angular? despite that I open the panel inspect in google chrome and nothing that shows me
Thank you for your helping me :)

Comment: why doont you put this code inside  ngAfterViewInit() method by implementing AfterViewInit interface

Comment: I created a new app and tested the code and it works fine for me. Are you sure `app.component.html` is the file referenced by `app.component.ts`. Also for debugging, you can add a `console.log('hello world', this.isAuth);` underneath to make sure your timeout is running properly.

Comment: It is also encourage that you make a demo through stackblitz for angular template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved successfully. The setTimeout () constructor definition should be in the same compoment.ts ie if we put the disabled button in the file first.compoment.html it is necessary that this definition of activation will be also in first. compoment.ts and the program will work well

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `isAuth` insted of `!isAuth`

`

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h2>Mes materiels</h2>
     <ul class="list-group">
       <app-materiel></app-materiel>
       <app-materiel></app-materiel>
       <app-materiel></app-materiel>
     </ul>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="isAuth" >Test Btn</button>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: At the beginning of this project the button is deactivated and after 4 seconds will be active